Why does a NodePort service on docker desktop for macos not actually bind to a port?
For a while, I've used a NodePort service in my kubernetes in docker desktop on an M3 macbook. It's worked fine until today.
Now, it's stopped working, giving me an error when trying to connect:
(venv) jwatte@Jons-MacBook-Pro dir % psql postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:30032/postgres
psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 30032 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

(lkctl is an alias for kubectl --context=docker=desktop)
The service is listening:
(venv) jwatte@Jons-MacBook-Pro dir % lkctl get service graph-postgres-local -n sandbox -o wide
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE     SELECTOR
graph-postgres-local   NodePort   10.104.142.18   <none>        30032:30032/TCP   7m41s   app=graph-postgres

The target pod exists:
(venv) jwatte@Jons-MacBook-Pro dir % lkctl get pod -n sandbox -l app=graph-postgres
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
graph-postgres-8449bf8697-t8kht   1/1     Running   0          5m51s

There are no processes listning on port 30032 locally:
(venv) jwatte@Jons-MacBook-Pro dir % netstat -nal | grep LISTEN | grep 32
(venv) jwatte@Jons-MacBook-Pro dir % 

Here's the service:
(venv) jwatte@Jons-MacBook-Pro dir % lkctl get service graph-postgres-local -o yaml -n sandbox
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"graph-postgres-local","namespace":"sandbox"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"postgres","nodePort":30032,"port":5432,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":5432}],"selector":{"app":"graph-postgres"},"type":"NodePort"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-07-02T22:35:04Z"
  name: graph-postgres-local
  namespace: sandbox
  resourceVersion: "2154965"
  uid: c5f3036e-a6b6-4f31-9fea-5c8657f9b929
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.104.142.18
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.104.142.18
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: postgres
    nodePort: 30032
    port: 30032
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    app: graph-postgres
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

FWIW, I've also tried with port: 5432 in the service specification, with no change.
I understand that docker has to run a VM internally to host these containers, but this used to work, and today it stopped working. I updated to the latest version as of today as well, but no change.

Did you create an Ingress for it? Until you do, the port is expose but to the "internal docker" network. The Ingress creates a path from the outside world to the inside.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/
Ideally you will want to have an ingress controller, which will be capable of handling multiple services from a single port. The most common ones are Traefik and NGINX-Ingress.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/
https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/kubernetes-ingress/
I would recommend starting with NGINX because it's simpler to grasp, but Traefik does some serious magic that makes things easier when you have lots of deployments and stuff.

Back when I learned Kubernetes, ingress didn't work locally, and only worked in hosted clouds (at least, that's what it seemed like to me.) (Also, kubernetes-in-docker-desktop wasn't really a thing, at the time I used bare kube on a bare linux VM.)
I'll try a local docker ingress now and see how that goes!
Oh, it looks like it still has the hostname problem. Having every developer in a company edit etc/hosts leads to a lot of support problems. But there are ways around that!

Make sure you give Docker the right permissions, Linux and other OSes don't like you using ports under 3000 without proper rights.
